# Access: Counting Number of Occurrences in 2 Columns

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on a database for work, and I need to figure out a way for Access to count the number of projects that each employee is assigned.  Projects have 1 or 2 employees assigned, and my boss needs to be able to quickly figure out how many projects each person is working on.  Below is an example table:

```
Project     Employee 1  Employee 2

Project A    John Doe    Jane Doe

Project B    Jane Doe    Sam Smith

Project C    Jane Doe    John Doe

Project D    Sam Smith   Anna Smith

Project E    Anna Smith  John Doe
```

And here is the result I'm looking for:

```
**Employee     # of Projects**

John Doe             3

Jane Doe             3

Sam Smith            2

Anna Smith           2
```

Comment: do you need instruction on how to do this or do you need an sql query? Please clarify in the question?

Comment: Also provide some more details on the tables so people who are able to answer use the relative fields related to your query. Change your field names if your worried!

Comment: I agree with other comments, but more specifically, is there another "Employee" table which contains a unique list of employees?  This would make the query much easier to construct (and would indicate a properly normalized database).  Either way you will need to perform separate sums for each column of the project, but if there is another table already with unique names, it avoids extra step of combining the results into a list of unique employees.

Comment: Too broad? I think those who flagged this question misunderstand the difference between answers which are too broad and the actual question.  The question lacked a bit of detail, but I was able to answer directly with a few queries.  Despite the OP's database was not normalized, the technique I outlined in my question is one that comes up often and it is worth sharing in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The table you described is probably not the best way to store the data and I think it's only making your job more difficult. The value of a relational database is that you can have data living in different tables but related based on primary/ foreign keys which makes it significantly easier to pull reports like the one you described. It seems to me like this table might have previously lived in Excel, and I would spend some time now establishing relationships in Access which will save you time and headaches later. I would suggest creating 3 separate tables: employees, projects, and project employee assignments.

The employee table should have 3 fields: EmployeeID, which should be set to AutoNumber in Design view and then selected as the primary key, First Name, and Last Name, both short text fields. This EmployeeID field will be referenced in the project employee assignments table.

The projects table should have 2 fields: ProjectID, also set to AutoNumber in Design view and selected as the primary key, and ProjectName which will also be a short text field. You can also add other fields, perhaps a text field for ProjectDescription would be helpful later on.

The Project-Employee Assignments table should have 2 fields: EmployeeID and ProjectID. If you aren't familiar with one-to-one, one-to-many, and many-to-many relationships I would suggest looking it up- you are describing a many-to-many relationship between the projects and employees, that is, one project can have many employees and one employee can be involved in many projects. This table exists to establish those relationships between employees and projects.

From here, go to the database tools tab and select Relationships. You'll need to establish a one-to-many relationship between the Employees table and the Assignments table on the EmployeeID field. You'll also need to establish a one-to-many relationship between the Projects table and the Project-Employee Assignments table on the ProjectID field.

Enter each relationship between projects and employees in the Assignments table. If you have a short list of projects and employees, you can do this directly in the table, but I'd suggest creating a form to do this with 2 combo boxes that each select from the lists of existing projects and employees, respectively. There are many tutorials about creating combo boxes that show informative columns, like employee name, but save the ID numbers to the table. Search "Bind Combo Box to Primary Key but display a Description field" for one example.

Finally, create a query to count projects per employee. You should include your Employees table, as well as your Project-Employee Assignments table. Select FirstName and LastName from the Employees table. Select both columns (EmployeeID and ProjectID) from the Project-Employee Assignments table. Unclick "show" for EmployeeID. Right-click anywhere in the query to get a menu of more options and click the sigma for totals. Set the total for EmployeeID, FirstName, and LastName to "Group By" and for ProjectID to "Count" then save the query. Run the query and enjoy having your totals!

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will try this out.  I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Could you please provide picture from the last paragraph in query window and/or giving it's code?

Answer (score 1):

Elizabeth Ham's answer is very thorough and I recommend following her advice, but knowing that sometimes we don't have time to do a complete overhaul, here's some instructions on how to get results from the given table structure.  As Elizabeth and I pointed out (in my comment), a single query could have gotten the requested data if the tables were complete and properly normalized.

---

Because there are multiple employee columns for which you want statistics, you need to join the given table at least twice, each time grouping on a different column and using a different alias.  It is possible to do this using the visual Design View, however it is usually easier to post questions and answers on StackOverflow using SQL text, so that's what follows.  Just paste the following code into the SQL view of a query, then you should be able to switch between SQL view and Design View.

Save the following SQL statements as two separate, named queries: `[ProjectCount1]` and `[ProjectCount2]`.  Saving them allows you to refer to these queries multiple times in other queries (without embedding redundant subqueries):

```
SELECT P.[Employee 1] As Employee, Count(P.Project]) As ProjectCount
FROM Project As P
GROUP BY P.[Employee 1];

SELECT P.[Employee 2] As Employee, Count(P.[Project]) As ProjectCount
FROM Project As P
GROUP BY P.[Employee 2];
```

Now create a UNION query for the purpose of creating a unique list of employees from the two source columns.  The UNION will automatically keep only distinct values (i.e. remove duplicates).  (By the way, UNION ALL would return all rows from both tables including duplicates.)  Save this query as [Employees]:

```
SELECT Employee FROM [ProjectCount1]
UNION
SELECT Employee FROM [ProjectCount2]
```

Finally, combine them all into a list of unique employees with a total sum of projects for each:

```
SELECT 
    E.Employee As Employee, nz(PC1.ProjectCount, 0) + nz(PC2.ProjectCount, 0) As ProjectCount
FROM 
    ([Employees] AS E LEFT JOIN [ProjectCount1] As PC1 
         ON E.[Employee] = PC1.[Employee])
    LEFT JOIN [ProjectCount2] As PC2 
        ON E.[Employee] = PC2.Employee
ORDER BY E.[Employee]
```

**Note 1**: The function `nz()` converts null values to the given non-null value, in this case 0 (zero).  This ensures that you'll get a valid sum even when an employee appears in only one column (and as such has a null value in the other column).

**Note 2**: This solution will double count an employee if it's listed as both [Employee 1] and [Employee 2] in the original table.  I assume that there are proper constraints to exclude that case, but if needed, one could do a *self join* on the second query [ProjectCount2] to exclude such double entries.

**Note 3**:  If you do decide to follow Elizabeth's advice and you already have a lot of data in the existing structure, the above queries can also be useful in generating data for the new, normalized table structure.  For instance, you could insert the unique list of employees from the above UNION query directly into a newly normalized [Employee] table.

Comment: Thank you!!  I really appreciate the time you took to respond to my question.  I will try your answer and Elizabeth's above.